# How to include image from Servlet in JasperReports dynamically?

Tags: java, servlets, jasper-reports

I have a `JasperReports` generated `PDF`. Now I want to include an image that is received dynamically from a `Servlet`.

I tried adding a static servlet url, anyways I get the following error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found at : de.my.servlet/get
    at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getBytesFromLocation(RepositoryUtil.java:195)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.RenderableUtil.getRenderable(RenderableUtil.java:120)
```

So how can I add an image dynamically?